# Asp net core identity server 4 oidc при выходе logoutId равен null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

в методе выхода identity server logoutId равен null не понимаю в чем проблема конфигурация identity сервера

```
 `public static class Configuration
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
        new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
        new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("ToDo", "Web API")
            {
                Scopes = { "ToDo" },
            },
            new ApiResource("Roles", "Roles")
            {
                UserClaims = { JwtClaimTypes.Role },
                Scopes = { "Roles" },
            }
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new ApiScope("ToDo"),
            new ApiScope("Roles")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "ToDoClient",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                RequirePkce = true,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    "ToDo",
                    "Roles",
                },
                AllowedCorsOrigins =
                {
                    "http://localhost:3000"
                },
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/signout-oidc" }
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "ToDoMVC",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                RequirePkce = true,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 120,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    "ToDo",
                },
                RedirectUris = {"https://localhost:44338/signin-oidc"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://localhost:44338/signout-callback-oidc"},
            }
        };
}
```

файл program identity сервера

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var connectionsString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ToDoConnectionString");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionsString);
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "ToDo.Identity.Cookie";
    options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
});

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddAspNetIdentity<AppUser>()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Configuration.IdentityResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Configuration.ApiResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Configuration.ApiScopes)
    .AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.Clients)
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Auth}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

метод выхода identity сервер

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(string logoutId)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        var logoutRequest = await _interactionService.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(logoutRequest.PostLogoutRedirectUri))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
        return Redirect(logoutRequest.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
    }
```

файл program MVC клиента

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<TokenService>();
HttpClient ToDoApi = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44355") };
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(config =>
    {
        config.DefaultScheme = "Cookie";
        config.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookie")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", config =>
    {
        config.Authority = "https://localhost:44385";
        config.ClientId = "ToDoMVC";
        config.ResponseType = "code";
        config.UsePkce = true;
        config.SaveTokens = true;
        config.Scope.Add("openid");
        config.Scope.Add("profile");
        config.Scope.Add("ToDo");
        config.UseTokenLifetime = true;
        config.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            // Вызывается, когда токен был успешно проверен и декодирован.
            OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                // Получаем access token из контекста аутентификации.
                var accessToken = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;

                // Получаем значение claim "exp" (время истечения токена).
                var expirationTime = int.Parse(accessToken.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "exp").Value);

                // Получаем текущее время.
                var currentTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();

                // Количество секунд до истечения токена.
                var secondsUntilExpiration = expirationTime - currentTime;

                // Проверяем, сколько времени осталось до истечения токена.
                if (secondsUntilExpiration < 40)
                {
                    var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
                    serviceProvider.GetService<TokenService>().RefreshToken();
                }
            }
        };
        // config.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
        // {
        //     var idTokenHint = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;
        //
        //     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idTokenHint))
        //     {
        //         context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
        //     }
        //
        //     return Task.CompletedTask;
        // };
    });

builder.Services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(ToDoApi);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ToDoService>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

метод выхода MVC клиента

```
public IActionResult Exit()
    {
        return SignOut("Cookie", "oidc");
    }
```

и на всякий случай файл program API

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddPersistance(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddApplication();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", policy =>
    {
        policy.AllowAnyHeader();
        policy.AllowAnyMethod();
        policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(config =>
    {
        config.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        config.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:44385/";
        options.Audience = "ToDo";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Лучше не добавлять "решено" в заголовок. Тыкните галочку рядом с ответом, чтобы отметить вопрос как решенный, или вообще удалите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя огромное количество времени дебагинга понял в чем проблема.... Проблема была в конфликтах Nuget пакетов, так что те кто столкнулся с такой проблемой проверьте не конфликтуют ли у вас Nuget пакеты!!!!!!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]